# Selenium - How to click OK button in a pop up using text containing in that button

Tags: selenium

The code below is shown in firebug for the OK button in the popup of my application

```
<button id="ext-gen219" class="x-btn-text" type="button">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;OK&nbsp;&nbsp;
</button>
```

Here the button id is randomly generated and also the position of ok button is not identifiable. Is there a way to click on the button by its text? Like the button contains a text called OK.

Comment: I think you have missed out something.

Comment: No my doubt when there is no space (&nbsp) before and after OK then this is working //button[contains(text(), "OK")] but the problem am facing is a pop up comes over another pop up and both have OK button. The code which i pasted above is the second pop up code. how to use text contains when space is there before and after text

Answer (score 4):

For Selenium IDE or Selenium RC, `xpath=//button[contains(., 'OK')]` ought to be a good locator.

Answer (score 0):

I am going on the premise that the text of the popup boxes are not identical so I would recommend something like this:

```
List<IWebElement> dialogBox = driver.FindElements(By.Class("dialogBoxClass");
int buttonIndex = dialogBox.FindIndex(i => i.FindElement(By.Class("DisplayedTextElementClass").Text.Contains("some unique text here"));
dialogBox[buttonIndex].FindElement(By.ClassName("x-btn-text")).Click();
```

This captures the parent element of all the dialog boxes and then parses each object to find the index of the box you want and then clicks on the 'Ok' button in the correct object.

Comment: Hi we are using keyword driven framework, hence i need the exact xpath

Comment: I guess I don't see how that makes any difference.  To me if you can capture the button element, then you can capture the wrapper element and then just build a custom method or class to parse wrapper to find your specific button.

Answer (score -1):

In case of a submit button this locator `css=input:submit[value="OK"]` should work. In case of a button element take `css=button:contains("OK")`.

Comment: No my doubt when there is no space (&nbsp) before and after OK then this is working //button[contains(text(), "OK")] but the problem am facing is a pop up comes over another pop up and both have OK button. The code which i pasted above is the second pop up code. how to use text contains when space is there before and after text

Comment: Contrary to what many people thing, there is no CSS ":contains" selector.  It was a proposal that was rejected during the CSS3 standards process.